# TypeError: <> is not a function. Stumped

Tags: javascript

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the console is telling me the functions persistSetting() and persistAllSettings() are not functions.

This is an angularJS controller.

Does it have something to do with the async method calls in the functions?

```
configApp.controller('settingsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.toPersist = {
    discreteValue: 6,
    qualityCheckBox: false
  };
  $scope.$watchCollection('toPersist', function(newConfigSetting) {
      this.persistSetting(newConfigSetting);
      this.persistAllSettings();
  });
  function persistAllSettings() {
      chrome.storage.sync.set(toPersist, function() {
        // notify user?
      });
  }
  function persistSetting(someSetting) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set(someSetting, function() {
      // notify user?
    });
  }
}]);
```

Comment: They are probably not part of `this` object. I see them defined there but they aren't really being part of any object. You probably don't need `this`.

Comment: That's exactly it.   Thanks, this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have local functions named `persistSetting` and `persistAllSettings`, but you're trying to call *methods* named `persistSetting` and `persistAllSettings` on an object that doesn't have methods with those names. (It's like how declaring a variable named `foo` doesn't suddenly make it available as `this.foo`.)

You most likely need to do one of the following:

- change `this.persistSetting` and `this.persistAllSettings` to `persistSetting` and `persistAllSettings`, respectively.
- set the `persistSetting` and `persistAllSettings` methods on that object to be the `persistSetting` and `persistAllSettings` functions, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Dont prefix functions visible in the scope with `this.`, as it is used to access instance methods.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('toPersist', function(newConfigSetting) {
    persistSetting(newConfigSetting);
    persistAllSettings();
});
```